# List updates in Team Explorer?

Tags: git, visual-studio, team-explorer

I have currently 29 local git repositories listed in the Team Explorer in Visual Studio. Is there any way to list those repositories that have cod that needs to be committed and/or pushed (synced) without having to open all the repositories one by one?

Comment: Write a bash script which loops through some set of directories, checks if the working directory is clean.

Comment: Also, read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48632860/989920, as it explains more about what "needs to be pushed" means.